# Get latest file from a directory using psftp

Tags: windows, unix, sftp, psftp

There are many files in a directory on a server which are generated by a process. How to get latest file (order by date descending) that is generated using psftp?

Answer (score 3):

The `psftp` does not have such feature.

You would have to:

- Run `psftp` once with `ls` command and output it to a file
- Parse the output using some scripting language, to find the latest file.
- Generate ad-hoc download script for the selected file for a second `psftp` run.

---

Instead, you can use [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting) and its [`get -latest` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get#latest) instead.

Example batch file (.bat):

```
winscp.com /log=download.log /ini=nul /command ^
    "open sftp://username:password@example.com -hostkey=""...""" ^
    "get -latest /remote/path/* C:\local\path\" ^
    "exit"
```

There's a guide for [Converting PuTTY PSFTP script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_psftp_script_to_winscp).

Or even easier, you can have [WinSCP GUI generate the script/batch file for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating). All you need to do manually is to add the `-latest` switch.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*